# PHP - Composer Autoload - Class not found

Tags: php

I'm having a problem with using autoloaded classes through composer.

Here is my file structure:

```
-cache
-public
-src
--Repository
---PostRepository.php
-index.php
-composer.json
```

I'm trying to load PostRepository.php in index.php.
But getting an error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'App\Repository\PostRepository' not
>   found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/index.php:12 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown
>   in /opt/lampp/htdocs/index.php on line 12

Here is my composer.json:

```
{
  "require": {
    "twig/twig": "^2.0"
  },

  "autoload": {
    "psr-4":  {
      "App\\" : "src/"
    }
  }
}
```

here is my PostRepository.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Repository;

class PostRepository
{
    ...
}
```

and here is my index.php

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

use App\Repository\PostRepository;

$postClass = new PostRepository();
$posts = $postClass->getAllPosts();

var_dump($posts);
```

It looks like namespaces are ok. What could be wrong?

Comment: The error occurs on line 12 according to your paste. However the posted index.php has only 9 lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should include the autoload.php before using any class.

try to make your code like this:

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

use App\Repository\PostRepository;
$postClass = new PostRepository();
$posts = $postClass->getAllPosts();

var_dump($posts);
```

then do

```
composer dump-autoload
```

---

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'App\Repository\PostRepository' not
>   found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/index.php:12 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown
>   in /opt/lampp/htdocs/index.php on line 12

htdocs/index.php !! do you have one project in htdocs?
because you should be referencing `htdocs/your-project-folder/index.php`

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this one, but getting the same error.

Comment: Are you referencing the correct index in the correct folder?

Comment: Oh my... You are right, project was in wrong directory on my localhost... Thanks